# Problems with rollback and @Transactional

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data

I have the following situation.

Assume that I have 2 @Services classes, inside each one I have a method annotated with @Transactinal.

The method of first class @Transactional and it calls the method of second class (in second class, the method is annotated with @Transactiona(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)).

```
public class Class1 {
    @Autowired
    private Class2 class2;
    @Transactional
    public void doSomeWork(Object value){
        dao.save(value)
        Object anotherValue = value.getAnotherValue();
        AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();
        anotherObject.setValue1("lorem ip");
        anotherObject.setAnotherValue(anotherValue);
        class2.doSomeWork(anotherObject)
    }
}

@Service
public class Class2{
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomeWork(){
        ...
        throws new RuntimeException("fail");
    }
}
```

I have observed that value (the object in first method) was rollback, but, now it have an database ID and is in the session cache.

I'm figuring out how to remove this object from session or how to evict this...

Any sugestions?

Comment: Did you set up spring to use CGI Proxies?  Are there actually interface classes that you ommitted?  Are you sure @Transactional is firing at all and you aren't just using hibernate in autocommit mode?

Comment: No, no, yes. The @Transactional annotations are used in many others parts of this application. Also, the rollback was done, but the session keeps the first object in his cache.. About the CGI Proxies, why shoud I use them? I've just set `proxy-target-class="true"`